# Node wait all async call before execute code

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I struggle for some days on a quite simple problem i guess.

I have multiple call like this

```
for(var i = 1; i <= timeToIterate;i++){
    xapi.fetch({})
        .then(function (response) {
            response.results.forEach(y => {
                yapi.fetch({})
                    .then(function (response2){
                        //some treatment here with
                        response.articles.forEach(article => {
                            finalArray.push({})
                        });
                    })
        });
}
```

No problem until then everything works fine but now i want to execute code with my finalArray after everything is finished. but when i tried to put a then after the second then but it don't execute well i tried to put after the for loop but still empty. I even tried with some await but i can't figure out how to execute code when all the then are finished.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT :  more test with the answer

```
var count = 0; //just to know how many articles
var completeArray = [];
var promise_arr = [];
xapi.fetch({})
    .then(async function (responseJson) {
        var timeToIterate = Math.ceil(responseJson.totalResultNumber / 50);
        for(var i = 1; i <= timeToIterate;i++){
            p = yapi.fetch({})
                .then(function (responseJson) {
                    if (responseJson.results.length > 0){
                            responseJson.results.forEach(x => {
                                zapi.fetch({})
                                    .then(function (response) {                            
                  response.articles.forEach(article =>{
                                         count++;
                                         console.log(count);
                                         completeArray.push({article};

                                     });

                                }).catch(e => {
                                    console.log(e);
                                 })
                            });
                        }
                    }).catch(e => {
                        console.log(e);
                     })
                     promise_arr.push(p);
                }
                await (Promise.all(promise_arr));
                console.log('now '+ completeArray.length);
                const  insert = elasticClient.bulk(
                    {body: completeArray},function (err, resp) {
                        completeArray = [];
                        if(resp.errors) {                                   
                            console.log(JSON.stringify(resp, null, '\t'));
                        }
                    });
            }).catch(e => {
                console.log(e);
             }).then(function(){
                return res.json(count);
            })
```

But it still trigger before the end of the for function. Did i miss something ? I will try with the second answer !

EDIT 2 : I tried the second answer too but can't find out how to get it work without error, i'm new with bluebird didn't knew it before today

```
var count = 0;
var completeArray = [];
let response0 = await api1.fetch({});

await Promise.map(response0.results, async z => {
    console.log(z); //Good log here
    var timeToIterate = Math.ceil(z.totalResultNumber / 50);
                for (var i = 1; i <= timeToIterate; i++) {
                    let response = await api2.fetch({});

                    await Promise.map(response.results, async x => {
                        console.log(x) // No Log here
                        let response2 = await api3.fetch({});

                        await Promise.map(response2, y => {
                            if (y.sections && y.sections.length > 0) {
                                y.sections.forEach(section => {
                                    if (section.articles.length > 0) {                                    
                                        lawSection.articles.forEach(article => {
                                            count++;
                                            console.log(count);
                                            completeArray.push(article)
                                        });
                                    }
                                })
                            } else if (y.articles && y.articles.length > 0) {
                                y.articles.forEach(article => {
                                    count++;
                                    console.log(count);
                                    completeArray.push(article);
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
                console.log('now ' + completeArray.length); // got this log Z time but nothing above so completeArray.length always = 0
                const insert = elasticClient.bulk({
                    body: completeArray
                }, function (err, resp) {
                    completeArray = [];
                    if (resp.errors) {
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(resp, null, '\t'));
                    }
                });
            });
```

EDIT 3 : Thanks to @tadman i figure it out but still have a problem of asynchronous for my elastic client here is my code

```
var count = 0;
var completeArray = [];
let response0 = await api1.fetch({});
    await Promise.map(response0.results, async z => {
        var timeToIterate = Math.ceil(response0.totalResultNumber / 50);
            for (var i = 1; i <= timeToIterate; i++) {
                let response = await api2.fetch({});
                await Promise.map(response.results, async x => {
                    if(response2.sections && response2.sections.length > 0){
                        response2.sections.forEach(section => {
                            if (section.articles.length > 0) {
                                section.articles.forEach(article => {
                                    count++;
                                    console.log(count);
                                    completeArray.push(article);
                                });
                            }
                        })
                    } else if (response2.articles && response2.articles.length > 0) {
                        response2.articles.forEach(article => {
                            count++;
                            console.log(count);
                            completeArray.push(article)
                        });
                    }
                });
                // I have to put it here because if i put it after the for loop the request http is to big and i have a 413 response. But the problem here is it didn't wait for the callback for the next 'for' loop iteration ! So i have the right number with my 'count' variable but didn't have the right number in my database 
                console.log('now ' + completeArray.length);
                await elasticClient.bulk( //how can i wait for the end of this and apply the completeArray = [] before the next iteration ?
                    {refresh: "wait_for",body: completeArray},
                    async function(err, response) {
                        completeArray = [];
                    if (err) { console.log(err); return; }
                    console.log(`Inside bulk3...`);
                    let errorCount = 0;
                    response.items.forEach(item => {
                        if (item.index && item.index.error) {
                        console.log(++errorCount, item.index.error);
                        }
                    });
                    console.log(`Successfully indexed items`);
                    }
                )
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using the built-in Promise by doing a combination of `map` and feeding the results into [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) which looks roughly like:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= timeToIterate;i++) {
  xapi.fetch({ })
    .then(response => {
      Promise.all(
        response.results.map(y => {
          return yapi.fetch({ })
            .then(response2 => {
                //some treatment here with
                response.articles.forEach(article => {
                  finalArray.push({ })
                });
              })
        })
      );
    });
}
```

This would be easier if you split things up into functions as there's a ton of nesting going on here. If you can use `async`/`await` that'd also massively simplify things.

[Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) has `Promise.map` which is a lot simpler as it combines those two steps into one.

Combining Bluebird and `await` you get something more readable like:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= timeToIterate;i++) {
  let response = await xapi.fetch({ });

  await Promise.map(response.result, y => {
    let response2 = await yapi.fetch({ });

    response.articles.forEach(article => {
      finalArray.push({ })
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer too, i tried with bluebird as you can see in my edit 2 but can't make it work either.

Comment: You seem to be on the right track, but try and "flatten" it out more by using `await` instead of `then`. It'd also help to take some of the "deeper" stuff and shunt that to an `async function` to make it easier to follow and, importantly, debug.

Comment: thanks to you @tadman i achieve to do it but can't find how to finish this. I put my EDIT 3 code so you can see my last problem. Thanks again

Comment: It's great you're working incrementally towards a solution but you may want to open up a new question with the new problems. There's a lot to keep track of here.

Comment: Thanks i will do !

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking is "how do I wait for all the async calls to finish before doing something." The answer is to use promise.all and store your promises in an array. Something like this

```
promise_arr = []
for(var i = 1; i <= timeToIterate;i++){
    p = xapi.fetch({})
        .then(function (response) {
            response.results.forEach(y => {
                yapi.fetch({})
                    .then(function (response2){
                        //some treatment here with
                        response.articles.forEach(article => {
                            finalArray.push({})
                        });
                    })
        });
        promise_arr.push(p)
}
await(Promise.all(promise_arr))
//your code here
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. I edited my question to try your way but i still can't figure it out, i still have the same problem.